# Concatenating time values

Tags: ms-access, date-format, number-formatting

I have a problem.

In my access database I have two fields with DateTime. I use them for when a meeting starts and ends.

I would like to concatenate them for a report, but 09.00 ends up as 9.0 so my desired "09.00 - 10.15" ends up as "9.0 - 10.15".

Please help.

Comment: You need to format the number as a string. If I recall correctly, this is done with a formatting mask of #.## in Access.

Comment: I have tried, using a calculated field. But I keeps truncating the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

A pound sign in a mask suppresses zeros. Change your pound signs to 9's. Or just use `Format([startdate],'Short Time') + ' - ' + Format([enddate],'Short Time')`